# Trigger useEffect based on an onClick of a button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React, so apologies about the probably simple question.

Assume I have the following code:

```
const myComponent = () => {

    const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);

    // Other code

    useEffect(() => {
    
        // Do something
    
    }, [someVar]);

        
    return (
        <button>Hello</button>
    )
}
```

Everything is great so far, and whenever `someVar` changes useEffect runs.

Now, is it possible to do the following?

```
const myComponent = () => {

    const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);

    // Other code

    useEffect(() => {
    
        // Do something
    
    }, [<button with ID helloButton clicked>]);  // <--------- this is what I want

        
    return (
        <button
            id="helloButton"
            onClick={() => {
                // Do on click related stuff
            }}
        >
            Hello
        </button>
    )
}
```

As you can see in the pseudo-code above, I want useEffect to be triggered by detecting the user clicked the button that has ID `helloButton`

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a effect instead of an event handler? Usually, effects are way more heavy weight, so if easily possible (like here) should be avoided to simplify (in many ways)

Comment: @Mafii - Thanks for your comment.  Well, the code I provided is super simplified. It is a complex solution, and in my implementation useEffect is triggered by code of another component, hence the reference to the ID.

Comment: @DustinSpengler - This is exactly what I thought, but again, it seemed convoluted to me. It looks like I am trying to trick useEffect with a button click. That said, I might resort to this. The reason I asked was to see if it is possible to trigger useEffect directly via detecting a button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the most obvious solution to me is that you move the content of the `useEffect` to a function and call this function on click:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);

  const myFunc = useCallback(() => {
    // Do on click related stuff
  }, [/*...*/])

  useEffect(myFunc, [myFunc]);

  return (
    <button
      id="helloButton"
      onClick={myFunc}
    >
      Hello
    </button>
  )
}
```

Now, if for some reason you don't want to do that, you can also use a state that you will change on click, and pass it in the dependency array of your `useEffect`. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);
  const [triggerEffect, setTriggerEffect] = useState(Date.now());

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do something
  }, [triggerEffect]);

  return (
    <button
      id="helloButton"
      onClick={() => {
        setTriggerEffect(Date.now());
        // Do on click related stuff
      }}
    >
      Hello
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a use case for the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);

  // Other code

  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
      // Do something
  }, []);

  return (
      <button
          id="helloButton"
          onClick={handleOnClick}
      >
          Hello
      </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following snippet?

In short, it gets the element id from `e.target.id` and sets it to `state`.
Inside of the `useEffect` we conditionally check if the `id` from `state` is equal to the `element id` and if this condition is `truthy` we then trigger the call there.
When the component will unmount `return () => {}` we set the value again to `0` to avoid infinite loops.

There are many ways to achieve the same, for instance, using the `useRef` hook. It can vary depending of the case.

I hope it makes sense.

You can play around if you will [codesandbox-io](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hooks-z1sfv5)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (someVar === "helloButton") {
      // example
      window.alert(someVar);
    }
    return () => {
      setSomeVar(0);
    };
  }, [someVar]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        id="helloButton"
        onClick={({ target }) => {
          setSomeVar(target.id);
        }}
      >
        Hello
      </button>
      <button
        id="button"
        onClick={({ target }) => {
          setSomeVar(target.id);
        }}
      >
        Good bye
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```